# I want to translate the checkbox string to checkbox object and check whether it is checked or not

Tags: gwt, checkbox

The below function sets the checkbox in the flextable. using sethtml()...

```
public void populateData(int index, CartItem newLine) {
    int i = 0;

    for (WebMenuAttribute attribute : columns) {
        String result = getPropertyValue(newLine, attribute.getName());
        if(!isWidget)
        this.setText(index, i++, result);
        else 
        this.setHTML(index, i++, result);**
    }
}
```

and i'm retreiving the checkbox using the following statement.

```
            String test = shoppingCartTable.getHTML(i, vendorIndex);
```

which returns me this string (when it is checked or unchecked in both cases)..

i want to convert this back to checkbox and check whether it is checked.
Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Returns this string                                                                                                         ** '<span value="false" class="gwt-CheckBox"><input tabindex="0" id="gwt-uid-469" value="on" type="checkbox"><label for="gwt-uid-469"></label></span>'**

Comment: Any reason you're not using setWidget and getWidget?

Comment: As i'm dynamically creating these checkboxes into flextable. setwidget is giving the alignment issues..

Answer (score 0):

You can get the element using document.getElementById and  the you can get the value of the object.
If you angular js this task will become very easy you can easily get object.
still you can try to get elment by id and the get the value

Comment: i don't no the element id's. As there can be any no of checkboxes as they are dynamically generated.

Comment: you can dynamically generate id's using some counter or some code. and then take based on the ids then only you can be able to identify the uniqueness